# Firebase Query.startAt(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) in Java

Tags: java, firebase

I'd like to emulate the following, to exclude initial data from my Firebase listener, but do it in Java.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<your instance>.firebaseio.com/messages');

var queryRef = ref.orderBy('created').startAt(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

queryRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
});
```

There doesn't seem to be a signature of .startAt() that would take ServerValue.TIMESTAMP (which is a Map in the Java SDK) as a parameter.  Is this query (using the Firebase server timestamp) simply not possible in Java?

Answer (score 3):

The [API doc says](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#query_startAt) `startAt()` can take `String`, `String, String`, `boolean`, `boolean, String`, `double`, or `double, String`. So no. You can't pass a `Map` containing TIMESTAMP.

You could achieve a similar result by using [.info/serverTimeOffset](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html)

```
Firebase offsetRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

And now you can use that in your query:

```
double serverTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
ref.orderBy('createdAt').startAt(serverTime);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach to get newly synced data.
This is the chat model I'm sending:  `new Chat(message, mUsername, uniquePathID, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`

And inside the onDataChange method you outlined in your answer I’m adding a ChildEventListener like so:  
`query.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(serverTime).addChildEventListener(ChildEvenListenerClass.this); `
But all the data from the node is being downloaded. What do you think would cause this? Thanks in advance. I’ll open a fresh question if you need more code